# problem showing the <br> text instead of breaking lines in angular6

Tags: html, angular

i have a text showing in the angular.

```
var text = 'The Zones We are Looking for a Reversal is6000<br><br>We Will Keep Close Eyes on it <br>But Keep in Mind That if We Break Below 6000 USD<br><br>Then This Time We Expect a Hard PullBack Towards 5250-5500 USD Levels<br><br>'

<div class="text">
  {{text}}
</div>

.text {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 150%;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

why on the html it is still showing the '< br >' instead of the breaking lines?

Comment: Bind `innerHTML` property i.e. `<div [innerHtml]="text"></div>` there must be a duplicate for this issue

Comment: <div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-bind-html` for binding with html elements too. `ng-bind` creates a text node.
Refer for [ng-bind-html](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp)
You can also use the pre tag. It will automatically provide line breaks wherever specified

```
<div class="text">
  <pre>{{text}}</pre>
</div>
```